# Fatal error message still shown after fix on customer browsers

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, cookie

I have fixed the fatal error:Allowed memory size exceeded by increasing my memory limit in my php.ini to 125M. But for some users 
they're still seeing the message, months after the fix.

I though the reason why they could still be seeing the message could be the cached version on their browser or something related to the Magento site.

I fixed this problem months ago and every now and again a users comes out of the wood work with the error message. When I view the site it's fine and when they clear their cache and cookies it works fine.

Anyone have an idea why this is still cache or appearing on their browser?

Comment: Fatal errors don't come from any cache, there must be pattern between those errors, like any particular search query, loading of a specific category page etc. Also, I don't think 125M is sufficient for running Magento.

Answer (score 0):

As @Prateek says, you don't simply "fix" a memory error. :) It is likely that the error your users see is still an error. The PHP error log on your server should tell you the same.

In my experience, Magento requires at least 256M to run.

One problem with this error is that it's sometimes not easy to reproduce. It depends - again citing Prateek - on the special query and functions executed at the moment and can also depend on the state of the cache, the other work the server has to do at the moment, whether your users have added things to the cart or you have added new products to the shop.

In some hosting environments, you can simply raise the memory_limit by adding this to your .htaccess-file:

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

Other environments require the php.ini file, or CPanel or another administration software. Again, some hosters don't allow you to raise this setting, in which case it's not the right hoster for Magento ;)

Be careful though - this is the maximum amount a single PHP request to you server is allowed to use, and if you only have about 2G RAM, you can do the math ;)

Comment: Thanks for your feed back, I've check my php.ini to see what I have increased the memory limit, it looks like this:
memory_limit = 1024M
max_execution_time = 80000
zend_extension=/usr/local/php53/lib/php/extensions/ioncube.so
zend_extension=/usr/local/php53/lib/php/extensions/ZendOptimizer.so'